# Can't use camera images from turtlebot on the workstation laptop

Tags: turtlebot, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've checked that  I can communicate to the turtlebot and from the turtlebot to the workstation.  On the workstation, I can check  rostopic list and the see camera topic that I want to use.  If I try to see the camera image in RViz nothing shows up but it also shows that the topic is there.

If I go onto the turtlebot laptop I can use RViz to see the camera without any problems.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54445/can%27t-use-camera-images-from-turtlebot-on-the-workstation-laptop/) by [jd](https://answers.ros.org/users/2939/jd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2013-02-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try to echo the image topic with `rostopic echo <camera_node>/image_raw`. If there is nothing in return, then there may be a configuration problem.

In this case double-check that `ROS_MASTER_URI` and `ROS_IP` environment variables are correctly set on **both** computers.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jd](https://answers.ros.org/users/2939/jd/) on 2013-02-06**:
I run

```
rostopic echo /camera/rgb/image_raw
```

And I never get any response back from the terminal.  But at the same time if I do

```
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_color
```

I can see the camera image.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-02-06**:
Did you check `ROS_IP` and `ROS_MASTER_URI`? I had the same issue a while ago and the problem was indeed in these.

**Comment by [jd](https://answers.ros.org/users/2939/jd/) on 2013-02-06**:
I got it working, somehow.  Not sure what, if anything, I did though.  I have trouble now though with losing the network connection.  Shortly after the workstation gets the camera image it just freezes and I can't ssh to the robot anymore.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-02-06**:
It can be a problem of network bandwidth. Try to use compression -- `Transport Hint` in `Camera` plugin in RViz.